# Implementation of PUSH Technology in IPhone OS

Tags: iphone

I had to make use of PUSH TEchnology in my IPhone app. I am very new to this. Can any one suggest me how to start up the things. I would be very thankful if i can get some sample codes for reference. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you're still not sure how to get started, check out the documentation: [Push Notification Intro](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). Please elaborate if you have any specific questions about Push.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [this excellent tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)